# What's the use of the \Finv symbol?

Tags: symbols, amsmath

AMS defines two symbols : `$\Finv$` and `$\Game$` (table 204, p.97 of The comprehensive LaTeX symbol List).

Despite having studied some math in my youth, I have never encountered those and could not find anything from Googling.

Could someone give a hint as to which part of science they are used in please?

Comment: You can assign any meaning that you want to them (provided that you specify your meaning) or just let them have their normal meaning (which I don't know).

Comment: I am not sure this question is on topic but for example https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%84%B2

Comment: Yes, that's more of a math question I guess. I bet that, if it's defined by AMS package, it must have a math meaning somewhere...

Answer (score 4):

\Game is ⅁ U+2141 you can search google for

`site:https://arxiv.labs.arxiv.org ⅁`

which not that unsurprisingly turns up game theory papers eg

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.01738.pdf

[image]

\Finv is Ⅎ (U+2132) is a bit harder to find.

Comment: On my machine and also [in the official Unicode code chart](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2100.pdf) the glyph for U+2141 is a capital letter G turned upside town, but the example you present shows a G that is mirrored vertically (identical to the glyph typeset with `\Game`). Still, the Unicode code chart has the information "= game" added to this code point. So, probably both variations have the same meaning.

Comment: @JasperHabicht hmm so it is, odd that paper came up in a search for the unicode code point, so font used probably had  ---variant--- wrong unicode mapping

Comment: I am not even sure a mirrored capital G is encoded in Unicode. From the explanation in the charts, it appears that ⅁ is indeed meant to be denote "game". Maybe, this symbol is just not exactly standardised.

Answer (score 4):

A use of `\Finv` has been identified in a not-yet-published paper.  The context is in the explication of a problem entitled "The forward problem."

The math context is

```
$
u(\mathbf{x}, t) = 0 \qquad
\mathbf{x} \in \partial \tilde{\Omega}, t \in [\Finv 0, T]
$
```

(This is a component of a larger display.)  The symbol appears in a position comparable to that used for `\exists`, that is, as a sort of prefix.

The following subject classifications are assigned to this paper:

- 35R20   Operator partial differential equations (= PDEs on
  finite-dimensional spaces for abstract space valued functions)
- 35K20   Initial-boundary value problems for second-order parabolic
  equations

Comment: Just to know: the piece of code above does not work with `ams` packages only, right?

Comment: In the [official Unicode chart](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2100.pdf), the information "= Claudian digamma inversum" is added to the code point =2132 TURNED CAPITAL F. Wikipedia tells me that during his reign, Roman emperor Claudius introduced three new letters to the latin alphabet of which one is this letter. So, maybe this glyph was originally not meant to be used in a math context, which of course does not explain why it has been encoded by packages like `amsfonts`.

Comment: @Sigur -- This code *should* work with only ams packages; it was unearthed for me by a former colleague in the AMS tech support group (and many thanks to him).  What he provided was a clip from a pdf file; I may have coded something incorrectly.  From the information provided, I think the likely "wrapper" was `\documentclass{amsproc} \usepackage{amssymb}`.  (`amsmath` is automatically loaded.)

Comment: @Sigur -- I did indeed code something wrong: the `\tilde` accent.  Fixed.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, Oh, sorry. I found the typo: the brace after `u`. I fixed. Thanks.